# Reactjs/html: function and redirection on card but doesn't execute when clicking children

Tags: html, reactjs, function, onclick, children

I'm having an issue with redirection and function execution on a card. The functions should execute when the card is clicked. It does the trick but the onClick() fails when I click the card's children (image and text). Anyone can give me a quick fix for this? :)

The card is a react-router-dom Link. Here's some code and a screenshot.

```
  return (
          <div className="prefab__items">
            {preconfigurated.map((item, index) => (
              <Link
                key={index}
                data-models={JSON.stringify(item.models)}
                onClick={saveConfig} // not executed when clicking children 
                to="/configurator" // executed when clicking children 
                className="prefab__card"
              >
                <img className="prefab__card__img" src={item.preview} alt={item.name} />
                <span className="headerTwo">{item.name}</span>
                <small>€{item.totalPrice}</small>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
  );
};
```

[[image: Preview of the card1]